# CSS outline not rendering correctly in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, outline

I'm a bit baffled with the way the CSS outline property is rendering on Firefox 7 or below.
It's clearly got a problem somewhere, but I just can't find it.

It works fine on all other main browsers (Opera, Chrome, IE, Safari).

I've added a couple of screenshots for reference. One from Firefox:

[image]

and the other from Chrome:

[image]

Here's the CSS:

```
form#commentform input:focus { outline: 2px outset #717377 }
```

Here's XHTML:

```
<form id="commentform">
      <div>
         <label for="name">
            <strong>
            Nom
            <span id="sname"></span>
            </strong>
         </label>
         <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="name" name="name" class="textbox" />
      </div>
...
</form>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Firefox outlines are drawn around the `box-shadow` (not inside).
So you will have to serve it (using a css hack) an additional rule: `outline-offset: -X` (X = shadow's length).

Comment: Cool!! It works. Thank you. Is there any reference on the web to find out about these minor issues, such as this one for Firefox?

Comment: Ooh-oh! It now ruins the rendering on Opera! Any suggestions?

Comment: @user7 like I said you need to use a CSS hack to serve it exclusively to Firefox.

Comment: Sorry. I just added the new css property to the main CSS file. I'll apply it exclusively for Firefox. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This *bug* will be fixed with Firefox 30: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=480888#c109.

Until then you could apply another box-shadow to the element, since you can have multiple box-shadows:

```
.element {
    box-shadow: your values old box-shadow, 0 0 0 2px #717377;
}
```